# Titanium Appcelerator: iPhone Development without a Mac (like PhoneGap)

Tags: ios, windows, mobile, titanium

I am about to embark on some mobile development projects but I'm doing a little homework first. My primary goal is to deploy to Android and iOS, but the latter is posing some problems because I do not have access to (nor do I have any interested in acquiring) a Mac.

Phonegap offers a cloud service where you can upload your mobile development project and they will do the building for you - no Mac required. From the Phonegap Build FAQ:

> Simply upload your web assets - a ZIP file of HTML, CSS and
>   JavaScript, or a single index.html file - to PhoneGap Build, point us
>   to your Git or SVN repository, or let us set up a git remote endpoint
>   that you can push to. Then we’ll undertake the compilation and
>   packaging for you. In minutes, you’ll receive the download URLs for
>   all mobile platforms.

I am leaning toward the development and native UI capabilities of Appcelerator, but since I do not have a Mac, is there any hope for me using Titanium for iOS development using something akin to PhoneGap's Build service?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you dont have a Mac you will not be able to develop, test, deploy, or put in the app store applications for iOS, with or without using Titanium.

Regardless, even if you were able to use a cloud build technology with Titanium (which does not exist) you wont be able to deploy your *final application* to the App Store because you have to have XCode for that, the same goes for PhoneGap.  [Check this here:](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/ios-builds)

> Note: Since PhoneGap Build uses Apple's standard development process to build applications, >you will need to sign up for their developer program to build iOS applications on PhoneGap >Build. You will also need a Mac to configure your certificate and provisioning profile.

Bottom line, unless you use a mac, your not legally deploying to the App Store.

Comment: Well, clearly my optimism is founded by ignorance :) Thank you for the  explanation. My immediate thought is "geez,can't we all just get along and develop some kind of... standard...?" but that is a philosophical discussion for other forums.

Comment: I agree with you, keeping the tools to develop for iOS out of the majority of peoples hands only serves to keep many great coders away from the platform.

Answer (score 2):

Don't be forgetting the registration fees that come with signing up as Both a google play & iOS developer.

I fear that using a remote service is going to cost you dearly in time, as you'll be significantly increasing your test cycle.

The cost of a second hand Mac mini is hardly going to impact any development budget, even charity work. And as the previous poster note, you can't legally deploy your completed build without a mac. If you made macs, wouldn't you do the same?

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted without explanation -- countered, as this was the approach I initially took to solve the same question this OP is asking.

Answer (score 1):

There are services cropping up like [Mobundler.com](http://mobundler.com) and [Foundry22.com](http://foundry22.com) which let you do end to end development without a Mac.

Foundry22 is a service similar to PhoneGap build, for Titanium SDK. Similar to PhoneGap build, it requires p12 bundle for iOS signing and Java keystore for Android. You can use service like Mobundler to create those using just your browser. You still need to pay to become part of iOS developer program.

Answer (score 1):

The answer here is outdated.
There is an Icenium platform which will allow you to build and put your app on App Store without using Mac at all.

http://docs.icenium.com/publishing-your-app/distribute-production/publish-ios