# IOS App Development in Windows System using Titanium studio

Tags: android, ios, titanium

I developed Application With TiTanium studio on windows, For Android and blackbery. I also want to built my written app for Apple IOS. can i make this on windows?

Comment: Whats the problem in my question

Answer (score 0):

In short NO. We cannot develop any application for iOS using Windows with Titanium. Because we need iOS SDK for iOS application development and for Windows we don't have IOS SDK. For more information you can check [this information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11991902/titanium-appcelerator-iphone-development-without-a-mac-like-phonegap) link.